# Sierpinski space question

Tags: general-topology

The wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space) says that

$\{ \emptyset, \{0\},\{0,1\}\}$ are closed sets and $\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ are open.

So, why $\{0\}$ is open and $\{1\}$ is closed?

Comment: As far as I understand, that is how it is defined. Depends on the topology you define.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article **defines** the topology as having the open sets $\emptyset$, $\{1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$, where the empty and whole set are by definition required to be in any topology on $X = \{0,1\}$. So that $\{1\}$ is open is true by definition.

This makes $\{0\}$ closed as the complement of the open set $\{1\}$ in $X$. Again by definition of a closed set, one could say. The closed sets of $X$ are exactly the complements of the open sets (complement with respect to $X$).

Comment: So, if you would define topology $\{\emptyset, \{1\},\{0,1\}\}$ as closed, then $\{0\}$ would be open. Is Sierpinski usually defined as it's in the wikipedia article?

Comment: @Zzz Yes. It doesn't matter how you define it, really (i.e. whether $\{0\}$ is open or $\{1\}$) as the results are homeomorphic (swap 0 and 1). What matters is that there is exactly *one* open singleton among the two points. The other one is then of course closed (and not open).